# How to interpret skype packet loss numbers?

Tags: skype, packet-loss

I'm using a fairly bad internet connection at the minute, and have turned on the ["Display technical call info" option](https://support.skype.com/en-gb/faq/FA10415/can-i-see-how-much-bandwidth-a-video-call-is-using). This shows a window with lots of numbers including both send and receive packet loss (see below for an example). I have two questions about the packet loss numbers:

- Why are there two numbers? What do they mean/what is the difference between them?
- I have seen the second number go over 100% (I have seen 104% and 133%, that sort of range). What does that mean?

[image: skype technical call info]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up [asking on the skype forums](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows/Why-are-there-2-numbers-for-packet-loss/m-p/975330)

From there:

> There is no publicly available documentation of Call Technical Info, so everything is just a guess. The two percentage values refer to total package loss and to an average for the last minute (running average over 1 min interval)). Why the percentage can sometimes be more than 100% is still a mystery (at least for me)

Thanks to [ruwim](http://community.skype.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/136) for providing that answer.

Comment: What about packet loss, just above the "Send packet loss"? And you know, in my case, the two numbers in "send packet loss" are nearly in sync (the second one is occasionally higher) so it can't be the moving average :( Also, I'm curious how Skype knows about receive packet loss; mine always shows zero, so I'm quite suspicious.

Comment: I've definitely seen positive numbers in all the packet loss fields. And I don't know how they do it, but one way you could know about receive packet loss is to have packet numbers that increment, so if you receive 1,2,3,6,7,8.9,10 but not 4,5 then you have 20% receive loss. I've also seen the two numbers differ significantly, with the second number varying over a bigger range, so the moving average seems plausible for the behaviour I've seen.